# Take out all but last occurence structure in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I learn lisp a few days ago, and I want to do is like following

1 `(1 2 3 4 1 5) ==>  ( 2 3 4 1 5)

What I cand do is to remove all the occurence, I cannot figure out how to preserve the last symbol.

here is my code

```
(defun test (X L)
  (cond ((null L) nil)
        ((equal X (last L)) (test X (butlast L)))    
        (t (cons (test X (butlast L)) (last L)))))
```

Thx for your reading my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, recursive, but not very efficient solution:

```
(defun remove-all-but-last (X L)
    (cond ((null L) nil)
           ((equal X (car L)) 
               (if (member X (cdr L)) 
                   (remove-all-but-last X (cdr L)) 
                   L)) 
           (t (cons (car L) (remove-all-but-last X (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: Thx you so much! The member function is so useful! I have solved other problems with it!!!

Comment: Cool. I'm happy I could come up with a working solution after 15 years of not writing anything in Lisp, but you should study the other solutions, they are much better!

Comment: endp is better than null in this case

Answer (score 4):

If this is not just an exercise or homework in recursion:

```
(defun remove-all-but-last (element list)
  (remove element list :count (1- (count element list))))
```

Or:

```
(defun remove-all-but-last (element list)
  (remove element list :end (position element list :from-end t)))
```

Comment: They are some optional challenging exercise problems!

Comment: Excellent stuff! Easy to see you know CL really well. +1

Comment: Way to go, Liang-Yu! Always nice to see motivated learners, and you're welcome. Thanks for the kind words, piokuc!

Answer (score 3):

The same, but in linear time :)

```
(defun remove-all-but-last (list element)
  (reverse
   (remove-if
    ((lambda (x)
       #'(lambda (y)
           (when (equal y element)
             (if x t (not (setf x t)))))) nil)
    (reverse list))))
```

---

And, as the name suggests, a contrived solution, but (!) does it in a single pass.

```
(defun remove-all-but-last-contrieved
    (list element &optional (test #'equal))
  (do ((c list (cdr c))
        constructed
        back-ref
        last
        last-seen)
       ((null c) back-ref)
    (if back-ref
        (setf last constructed
              (cdr constructed) (list (car c))
              constructed (cdr constructed))
        (setf constructed (list (car c))
              back-ref constructed))
    (when (funcall test (car c) element)
      (if (or last-seen last)
          (when last-seen
            (rplacd last-seen (cddr last-seen)))
          (setf back-ref nil constructed nil))
      (setf last-seen last))))
```

Comment: Perhaps it is still too difficult for me, but I appreciate your help! Thx you!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using lambda rather than let in the first solution ? I took some time counting parens, nil should be on its own line. Also is #' really needed before (lambda ..) ? Second solution looks quite fast !

Comment: Assuming you wrote `remove-all-but-last-contrieved` for performance reasons: Did you actually compare its performance with my one-line solutions? For example, on my machine, CCL, optimizing speed, there was no significant difference for lists of 100k, 1 million, and 50 million random integer elements.

Comment: Interesting. I don't see anything near such speedups with a hardcoded equality operation. (Adding a `:test` optional parameter to my version doesn't make much of a difference either, btw.) I tried with different ranges of random numbers (3-10k), and – as you said – it didn't make much of a difference. You're also right as far as ideal computers are concerned. Always wanted to get one of those. :)

Comment: Thanks. Running the same code on CCL, I still see [considerably less difference](http://pastebin.com/UB3a1bMZ). (I added GCs in between, to get less variance, but still GC time matters, as your version tends to spend relatively more time GCing.)

Comment: Hm, in CCL, functions entered at the REPL are compiled. I didn't actually test this, but I assumed it would make no difference in implementations without an interpreter. Anyway, this isn't a shootout, and even if it were, SO comments wouldn't be a good place. :) You're also right in that this teast isn't really realistic. What matters to me is that my one-line approaches compare fairly well against an implementation written with efficiency in mind. Thanks for your time and effort!